# App data clearing 1 minute after install - BackupManagerService Timeout

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-backup-service

I just updated my app to API 23. Every time I prefer a fresh install, I can use the app for about a minute before it crashes and any data I've entered so far disappears. Here are the facts:

- I've been using the same Google account for testing both on physical devices and emulators, with debug versions and signed APK. (probable cause of "Signature mismatch" in log.)
- The log shows a "Signature Mismatch" message when attempting to restore.
- 60 seconds later, the log shows `E/BackupManagerService: Timeout restoring application ...`
- The app is then force killed and I see lots of entries about `clear data` and `ClearDataReceiver` and then `AccountUtils: Clearing selected account for [package]`

Why is this happening? Is it due to the signature mismatch? Why would the OS *ever* clear user's data just because a restore failed?

My backup config in my manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/mybackupscheme"
```

The backup scheme (default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
</full-backup-content>
```

My Backup Helper:

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Log.d("MyApp.MyBakAgent", "onCreate called");

        FileBackupHelper myDb = new FileBackupHelper(this, "../databases/" + DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME);
        addHelper(DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, myDb); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
         ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        Log.d("MyApp.MyBacAgent", "onBackup called");
            synchronized (DBAdapter.dbBackupLockObject) {
                    super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
            Log.d("MyApp.MyBakAgent", "onRestore called with version " + String.valueOf(appVersionCode));
            synchronized (DBAdapter.dbBackupLockObject) {
                   try {
                       super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
                   } catch (Exception ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                   }
            }
    }
}
```

Relevant LogCat (filtered for mentions of package, can provide more)

```
01-11 21:37:10.881 3588-3588/? D/RCPManagerService: App Installed with packageNAme = com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:37:11.311 3588-3588/? D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.NSouth.NSouthApp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
01-11 21:37:11.311 3588-3588/? D/BackupManagerService: Now staging backup of com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:37:11.331 3588-3588/? V/EnterpriseBillingPolicyStorage: getBillingProfileForVpnEngine - start - com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:37:11.391 3588-3588/? D/KnoxMUMContainerPolicy: packageInstalledForExternalStorage com.NSouth.NSouthApp

. . .

01-11 21:38:10.241 3588-4061/? E/BackupManagerService: Timeout restoring application com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.251 3588-4061/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.251 3588-4061/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.NSouth.NSouthApp appid=10459 user=0: clear data
01-11 21:38:10.251 3588-4061/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 19562:com.NSouth.NSouthApp/u0a459 (adj 0): stop com.NSouth.NSouthApp cause clear data
01-11 21:38:10.261 3588-4061/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{3f90827e u0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/.Activity_Course t12626}: app died, no saved state
01-11 21:38:10.261 3588-4061/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.261 3588-4061/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.291 3588-4061/? I/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{3a98b6d4 u0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/.Activity_Main t12626}
01-11 21:38:10.291 3588-4061/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.311 3588-4061/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.NSouth.NSouthApp appid=10459 user=0: clear data
01-11 21:38:10.311 3588-4061/? I/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{3a98b6d4 u0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/.Activity_Main t12626 f}
01-11 21:38:10.311 3588-4061/? W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{3a98b6d4 u0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/.Activity_Main t12626 f}
01-11 21:38:10.321 3588-4061/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.321 3588-4061/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.461 3588-4343/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{1847ccd8 u0 d0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/com.NSouth.NSouthApp.Activity_Main}
01-11 21:38:10.531 3588-3784/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{2ed8de84 u0 d0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/com.NSouth.NSouthApp.Activity_AddCourse} couldn't find taskId=12626 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1246 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1936 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2520 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1601 
01-11 21:38:10.531 3588-3784/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{2ed8de84 u0 d0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/com.NSouth.NSouthApp.Activity_AddCourse} couldn't find taskId=12626 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1246 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1936 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2520 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1601 
01-11 21:38:10.711 20089-20089/? I/ClearDataReceiver: [#DCM#] Intent Data: package:com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.781 20089-20089/? I/ClearDataReceiver: [#DCM#] Intent Data: package:com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:10.821 3588-3784/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{2ed8de84 u0 d0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/com.NSouth.NSouthApp.Activity_AddCourse} couldn't find taskId=12626 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1246 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1936 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2520 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1601 
01-11 21:38:10.821 3588-3784/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{2ed8de84 u0 d0 com.NSouth.NSouthApp/com.NSouth.NSouthApp.Activity_AddCourse} couldn't find taskId=12626 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1246 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1936 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2520 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1601 
01-11 21:38:11.211 20089-20089/? I/ClearDataReceiver: [#DCM#] Intent Data: package:com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:11.251 16844-20183/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED and uri=com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:11.261 16844-20183/? D/AccountUtils: Clearing selected account for com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:11.291 16844-20183/? I/LocationSettingsChecker: Removing dialog suppression flag for package com.NSouth.NSouthApp
01-11 21:38:11.311 16844-17661/? I/Icing: doRemovePackageData com.NSouth.NSouthApp
```

### Update

I've learned some things.

- First, the [BackupManagerService source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/jb-mr0-release/services/java/com/android/server/BackupManagerService.java) clearly shows that *app data is cleared and the app is closed* if the restore operation fails. (See `agentErrorCleanup` and `handleTimeout()` for the restore operation.)
- Second, none of the methods in `MyBackupAgent` are being called (debug logs are not being written, nor does it stop on break points). In other words, it doesn't look like I have any way to handle this issue.

So... **is this what we should expect if signatures don't match?** I suppose this shouldn't happen in production, so maybe it's okay...?

**Update 2:** Also occurring if the app's backed up version is greater than the just-installed version. Again, shouldn't happen in production, but still kind of ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if you look at the BackupManagerService code, the restore timeout is 60 seconds.

If your restore takes over 60 seconds, it fails.

The methods in MyBackupAgent are not being called because they are part of another process. The way you can debug the code is to log the messages (Log.v).

Had the same problem, trying to unzip a 1MB file, my restore was also timing out. The solution I found was to move the file unzipping to outside of onRestore.

So keep your onRestore as lean as possible.

```
class BackupManagerService extends IBackupManager.Stub {
    ...


    // Timeout interval for deciding that a bind or clear-data has taken too long
    static final long TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
    // Timeout intervals for agent backup & restore operations
    static final long TIMEOUT_BACKUP_INTERVAL = 30 * 1000;
    static final long TIMEOUT_RESTORE_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;
```